# input values into an array, using different class files

Tags: java

I have the following code:
1st file:

```
public class StudentServices {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Student student = new Student();
    Student[] array = new Student[5];

    public void setStudentInfo(){

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
            student.name = scan.nextLine();

            array = new Student[i];
        }
    }

    public void displayStudentInfo(){

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            System.out.println("Student Name: "+ student.name);
        }  
    }    
}
```

2nd file:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
}
```

The output i am getting when i enter 1,2,3,4 and 5 is:

```
    Student Name: 5
    Student Name: 5
    Student Name: 5
    Student Name: 5
    Student Name: 5
```

I know with the class file it is complicated, but it has to be done this way. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: from the looks of things his question is why does he get 5 5 5 5 5 instead of 1 2 3 4 5, for the student name;

Comment: when i enter 1,2,3,4 and 5 i want the output to be 1,2,3,4 and 5 not 55555.

Comment: @Ludjer, if so, the reason is: durring the Loop at setStudentInfo() a new instance of the Array is created.

Comment: sorry for being to vague

Comment: @KnusperPudding well yeah it the fact that he is setting the wrong students name as well as in his output he prints on the same student. He does not specify his array index using the [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is in your forloop's code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        array[i] = new Student();
        System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
        array[i].name = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

Give the above code a try.
I assign a new student to the array at index i. I then read the name in and store it in that students name.

Also your output code should change

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println("Student Name: "+ array[i].name);
    }
```

Your problem is that you do not use your array correctly. An array works exactly like a variable but you access your elements with specifying a index which is a int.

Go look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html it shows you how to use an array properly.

Comment: The second is printing - may add a fix for that too :) (i threw my answer away)

Comment: @ Ludjer - are we using the variables in the second file, cause when i removed the object for class Student(2nd file) it showed no error????

Comment: @prabhav4947 the student[i].name is a member variable(a member variable is a variable that is stored in a class). You must remember student object in the first class is not used since i use it in the array. Go read through the java docs i sent on arrays. It has a detailed explanation of arrays on how to use them. Arrays basically work like variables but you can have multiple per reference ie student[1], student[2] point to different students.

Comment: @prabhav4947 Please remember to accept the answer that is most correct. As well as up vote any of the other answers that deserve a up vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setStudentInfo(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){          
            System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
            Student student = new Student();
            student.name = scan.nextLine();
            array[i] = student;
        }
    }

 public void displayStudentInfo(){

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        System.out.println("Student Name: "+ array[i].name);
    }  
}
```